# ng-click functions execute in wrong order

Tags: angularjs

I have a table that has multiple pages and a navigation to scroll through the pages. I have a function in my ng-click "refill_checkboxes" that should be executed after the next page is rendered but it is always executed first. How can I do it the right way?

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Term</th>
        <th class="check">Check</th>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="term in data | slice:panel.offset:panel.offset+panel.size" ng-show="showMeta(term)" ng-attr-id="{{term.id}}">
        <td>{{term.label}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-click="switch_TermsCheck(term,this)" ng-attr-id="{{term.id}}" value="term" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div>
    <i ng-click="panel.offset = (panel.offset + panel.size);refill_checkboxes(this);" ng-show="data.length > panel.offset+panel.size" class='icon-arrow-right pointer'></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Please let me know if my answer solved your problem by accepting it/commenting it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is single threaded and ng-click is executed in the correct order as far as I know. You can move your function call to the next tick this way :

Create a function :

```
//don't forget to include $timeout in your controller
$scope.goNext = function(that) {
    $scope.panel.offset = ($scope.panel.offset + $scope.panel.size);
    $timeout(function() {
        refill_checkboxes(that)
    }, 0);
};

<i ng-click="go
Next(this)" ng-show="data.length > panel.offset+panel.size" class='icon-arrow-right pointer'></i>
```